# PC is hold/pushing buttons when I start it up

Tags: windows-10

I need to start the PC and then restart it for the computer to work.

So the resone i need to restart the PC is, when I try to write something, the left arrow is pressed. for example, if I have to write the word "write" it type it as etirw, the marker is continuously moves to the left.
Even if I go into a finished document and pick out the keyboard connector and then press at the bottom of the page with the mouse so the cursor will go to the left step wise as if I was holding the left arrow until it reaches the top of the page. Also,

And if, for example, I enter the windows menu or mark a file on desktop the computer scrolls between the alternatives as if holding down TAB.

another problem I have, (maybe they are not related) When I finish with pc, for example, when I played a game or write a document. I have to wait for just over 10 seconds before shutting down otherwise the computer deletes the last thing I was doing.

I have tried to reinstall windows, a factory reset. But it does not help.
I have also tried disconnecting the keyboard to see if it is the keyboard it is due to. But it does not help.

https://youtu.be/atRaa5IX0Ds

https://youtu.be/DJpMMTmMqzY

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your keyboard or localization perhaps set to Arabic, Hebrew or some other language that's read right to left?

Comment: "I have to wait for just over 10 seconds before shutting down otherwise the computer deletes the last thing I was doing." - You need to provide more information about this behavior, keyboard or localization issue, would not cause user files to be deleted.

Comment: YES it's like writing in Arabic. But the letters are western. @Peregrino69

Comment: I do not think the problems are connected either, but the problems arose at the same time @Ramhound

I do not think I can provide anymore to the behavior, only that, When I shut down a game on steam and immediately after that shut down the computer. the next time i use the PC, need to install the game again.

Comment: Letters are western because you're using a western font. That has nothing to do with system's keyboard settings or localization. You could show screenshots of those. Please don't answer in comments, update your question with new info. [This](https://itectec.com/superuser/how-to-change-the-text-direction-on-windows/) might help - found googling windows text left to right

Comment: Do not know who to edit the question...:/
Anyway, it did not help. 
even if I go into a finished document and pick out the keyboard connector and then press at the bottom of the page with the mouse so the cursor will go to the left step wise as if I was holding the left arrow until it reaches the top of the page.

Also, if I mark a file on the desktop, it jumps between the files, like am pressing the TAB key. @Peregrino69

Comment: To edit the question click Edit at the bottom of your question. Then you can re-write and re-format it however you will.

Comment: Can i add, a video or something to show you?

Comment: You can make a video, upload it somewhere and add a link to your question. However the issues are pretty clear. What's not is your keyboard and localization settings, and those you can show just with screenshots.

Comment: So uploaded my first video on youtube. Excuse the filming technique Link, is posted above @Peregrino69

Comment: @sam Besides the keyboard and mouse, do you have any additional hardware input devices connected (e.g. game controllers, etc.)? Unfortunately, I couldn't tell from the video.

Comment: @Anaksunaman 
No, nothing out of the ordinary.
Mouse
keyboard
Audio cable
internet cable
HDMI (screen)
DP (screen)